# Notepad autosave that doesn't switch tabs / notepad++ equivalent

Tags: text-editors

I like notepad++ because it's nice and minimal, but it bothers me that Notepad++ has no autosave. I looked into plugins and found this one:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/482781/topic/3983315

Unfortunately, this plugin scrolls to the top of the file / switches to the first tab when it does its magic. This is highly disruptive. Is anyone away of a better autosave for notepad++?

Failing that, what other super-light weight text editors do people use? (I mostly need it for Python/HTML/CSS/Javascript; I really like syntax highlighting and (un)commenting codeblocks)

Comment: Valid Question ?This is SO...Go through this first : http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 0):

Super-light weight text editor with syntax highlighting?

Vim.