# Notepad-like text editor with autosave

Tags: windows-xp, notepad, autosave

I like to use notepad to take simple notes during my work (todo lists, notes etc.). Unfortunatelly, I am missing autosave feature, because when system [freezes](https://superuser.com/q/841500/93604) the notes are lost.

Is there any simple, Notepad-like text editor for Windows XP which has autosave feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) it has a backup function which recovers your previous session. Including unsaved files.

Comment: Thanks Rik. Do you have personal experience with the Notepad++'s autosave feature? I've been looking around and it seems there are lots of problems: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24471044 http://superuser.com/q/483218

Comment: The latest version of Notepad++ is using a built-in backup function  (Settings->Preferences->Backup) and is not relying on a plugin. That is what they are talking about in the other question.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Evernote - https://evernote.com/

It's free and it auto saves the notes you make. It can also be synced to other devices like your cellphone, tablet and computers at home, so that you can have more than one source of your notes if the computer freezes again.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Is it actually a plain text editor?

Comment: No unfortunately it's a Rich Text Editor.

Comment: Evernote grew up with serious usability problems -- mostly related to rich text 
 handling, honestly -- which were not addressed before the company went into cash-grab mode and severely limited the free version.  Not a good option since 2016 or so.